# Генерация числа для игры "Быки и коровы"

Tags: python

уважаемое сообщество. Я - абсолютный новичок в программировании,  пишу игру Быки и коровы на Python.
У меня следующий вопрос. По правилам игры не должно быть повторяющихся цифр в загаданном трехзначном числе.  У меня проблема в области кода, который загадывает число.

```
    import random    
    number_player1 = ' '    
    digit1 = str(random.randint(1, 9)) 
    digit2 = str(random.randint(0, 9))
    digit3 = str(random.randint(0, 9))
    if digit1 != digit2 and digit2 != digit3 and digit1 != digit3:
        number_player1 = digit1 + digit2 + digit3
    else:
        здесь мне непонятно, какое действие выполнить
```

Наверное, лучше всего было бы выполнить возвращение в начало программы для повторного загадывания числа, но с циклами я затрудняюсь что-то делать.
И еще: программа учебная, все дальнейшие преобразования(ввод отгадываемого числа, подсчет собственно быков и коров) производятся с помощью строкового типа данных, так что желательны 'косметические'  изменения программы, а не полная ее переделка.
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идея такая:

первую цифру Вы генерируете произвольно.

Вторую - до тех пор, пока она совпадает со второй. как только перестала совпадать - можно идти дальше! (вероятно, это произойдет с первой попытки, но здесь важен сам принцип)

Третью - надо после генераиции сравнивать с первой и второй, как только она отличается от них обоих - все, дело сделано!

И на "псевдокоде" я, отвечая на Ваш вопрос, написал это так:

```
    import random    
        number_player1 = ' '    
        digit1 = str(random.randint(1, 9)) 
        do
            digit2 = str(random.randint(0, 9))
        while ( digit2 == digit1 )
        do
            digit3 = str(random.randint(0, 9))
        while ( digit3 == digit1 || digit3 == digit2 )
        number_player1 = digit1 + digit2 + digit3
```

Но, есть проблема, о которой я забыл: к сожалению, в Python цикл с постусловием отсутствует!

Поэтому в реальности код становится несколько более громоздким:

```
    import random    
    number_player1 = ' '    
    digit1 = str(random.randint(1, 9)) 
    while True:
        digit2 = str(random.randint(0, 9))
        if digit2 != digit1:
            break
    while True:
        digit3 = str(random.randint(0, 9))
        if digit3 != digit1 and digit3 != digit2:
            break
    number_player1 = digit1 + digit2 + digit3
    print (number_player1)
```

Но этот код я уже проверил - работает!

Comment: А чем можно заменить do? Вроде бы в Python нет такой конструкции...

Comment: прошу прощения, долго не писал на питончике. Сейчас исправлю!

Comment: я исправил ответ, предварительно проверив программу в питончике

Comment: Спасибо огромное!  Много плюсов в карму!!!

Comment: "Много плюсов в карму": у Вас есть такая совершенно легальная возможность - если ответ Вам действительно помог, вы можете его отметить "принятым". Это - такая зеленая галочка слева от заголовка ответа, рядом со "счетчиком голосов". Самое удивительное, что при этом "карма" растет не только у меня, но и у Вас

Answer (score 2):

В random есть функция выбора указанного количества элементов из данной последовательности - sample(seq, n).

```
import random
random.seed(a=None, version=2) # на алгоритм не влияет, но увеличивается случайность результата
n = random.sample("0123456789", 3) # 3 неповторяющихся элемента из 0123456789
if n[0] == "0": # если первая цифра получилась 0
    n[0] = random.randint(1, 9)
```